# How to copy files from Linux server to Microsoft OneDrive

Tags: linux

We have large files which we need to upload it to OneDrive from Linux. Currently, we are downloading it to local and uploading to OneDrive (Double effort). Is there a quicker way?

Comment: have you used a search engine to search for `linux onedrive` - there's a **LOT** of information on how to do that

Comment: Assuming that "from Linux" means some Linux server, checkout [rclone](https://rclone.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804301/how-to-sync-onedrive-business-office-365-on-linux) and the client. It monitor folder `~/OneDrive`. So if you download files in this directory they will be sync automatically with OneDrive

[Here](https://abraunegg.github.io/) you can find the client.